# aws_api_gateway_integration URI for kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-kinesis

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "kinesis_integration" {
  rest_api_id          = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.shippeo_api_kinesis.id
  resource_id          = aws_api_gateway_resource.shippeo_api_resource_kinesis.id
  http_method          = aws_api_gateway_method.post_json_files_kinesis.http_method
  type                 = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                  = aws_kinesis_stream.shippeo-kinesis-stream.arn
  integration_http_method     = "POST"
  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_resource.shippeo_api_resource_kinesis
  ]
}
```

I want to create an API Gateway that sends data to a kinesis stream. I am trying the code above but I get this error:

```
Error creating API Gateway Integration: BadRequestException: AWS ARN for integration must contain path or action
│ 
│   with module.shippeo-api.aws_api_gateway_integration.kinesis_integration,
│   on ../../modules/shippeo/kinesis-api.tf line 62, in resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "kinesis_integration":
│   62: resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "kinesis_integration" {
```

I read in another SO answer that the format of the uri is supposed to be like this:

```
arn:aws:apigateway:{region}:{subdomain.service|service}:{path|action}/{service_api}
```

How can I change it to use it with kinesis? What is the action or service_api?

region = "eu-central-1"

Answer (score 0):

From Terraform documentation, the URI should be of the form

```
arn:aws:apigateway:{region}:{subdomain.service|service}:{path|action}/{service_api}
```

So in your case, the URI would be:

```
arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1:kinesis:action/PutRecord
```

Reference:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_integration

Comment: still the same error:(

Comment: do I put this as a string?